# Circular Dependency Error, Blank when 0

Tags: google-sheets

I have tried both of these in Google Spreadsheets and continue to get circular dependency errors. I am trying to show blank when the result is 0. New values are entered daily and want to have the average formula run down the entire column so I don't have to drag the previous day's box down to copy the info.

```
=IF(C19="","",sum(C14:C18))

=IF(C19="0","",sum(C14:C18))
```

Comment: What cell are you putting the formula into?

Comment: Need a running average of cells that are not in a range.  Originally thought if the formula for the cell resulted in blank instead of 0 that it would not be included in the average.  Now trying the averageif function but get error re: wrong number of arguments.  Here is link to spreadsheet.  See row C4, E4, G4 for various attempts.  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DVNtyGyvnXw9uPRJEKzRNIEaypvouOXJev_5WmtjMU0/pubhtml

Comment: That link will not let you view formulas.  Here is another link:  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DVNtyGyvnXw9uPRJEKzRNIEaypvouOXJev_5WmtjMU0/edit#gid=1309660136

Answer (score 2):

```
=average(C:C)
```

should average the whole of ColumnC's numeric values, without difficulties over text or spaces in that column, while responsive to changes in ColumnC entries - with the proviso that the formula should not be in ColumnC.

Comment: Need a running average of cells that are not in a range. Originally thought if the formula for the cell resulted in blank instead of 0 that it would not be included in the average. Now trying the averageif function but get error re: wrong number of arguments. Here is link to spreadsheet. See row C4, E4, G4 for various attempts. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DVNtyGyvnXw9uPRJEKzRNIEaypvouOXJev_5WmtjMU0/edit